# Problem developing "Windows C / C ++ desktop application" to connect Windows10 to a bluetooth 5.0 device

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2017, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm building a Windows Desktop application in C/C++ VS2017 for BLE5.0.
If I pair the bluetooth of my Windows computer through the control panel, my application is able to receive/send bluetooth messages.

My problem is to establish a connection without making the association from the control panel.

Do you know if there are any Windows functions/messages that allow me to scan for bluetooth devices and then make a connection?

Thank's a lot
Bye

Comment: Use WinRT Bluetooth API or any third party library.

Comment: I don't recommend mixing C and C++; they are two distinct languages.  Pick one language to program in and edit your tags accordingly.  For example, C++ has `std::string` and C doesn't.

Comment: My language is C, but if you gave me some ideas to make the bluetooth connection in C ++, I would convert the project to C ++.